# java generic type conclusion

Tags: java, generics, types

Look at classes structure. I have models and views;

```
abstract class Model {
}

abstract class View <M extends Model> {
     public M model;
     View(M model) {
        this.model = model;
     }
}

class ButtonModel extends Model {
   public String text;
}
class ButtonView extends View<ButtonModel> {
     public Runnable onClickRunnable;
     ButtonView(ButtonModel model) {
          super(model);
     }

}
```

I want to write fabric of View with Type safe.

```
 public static <T extends Model> View<? extends T> build (T model) {
    if (model instanceof ButtonModel)
        return new ButtonView((ButtonModel)model);
    else if(...)
}
```

why I need to cast new ButtonView to View ? How can I write it more clean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're over-complicating things.  You don't really need generics here, just use good old method overloading:

```
public static ButtonView build (ButtonModel model) {
    return new ButtonView(model);
}

public static SomeOtherView build (SomeOtherModel model) {
    return new SomeOtherView(model);
}

// etc
```

Writing an overloaded method for each model type is no different from writing a single method containing an `instanceof` for each model type.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to adda `View<?> createView()` abstract method to your `Model` class (and it seems you want to keep your model classes independent from the view layer - which is a good point) then you won't be able to make it much simpler. If you want to map a class hierarchy to an other, more or less parallel class hierarchy (mapping the Model hierarchy to the View hierarchy in this case) then you will need that factory method which uses that dirty instanceof and casting.

Answer (score 0):

> why I need to cast new `ButtonView` to `View` ? How can I write it more clean?

The problem is with your `ButtonView` constructor it accepts exact `ButtonModel`, but not `Model`. You can rewrite this constructor, but will need to do same casting inside of your `ButtonView` constructor in case of future  needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  public static <V extends View<T>, T extends Model> V build(T model, Class<V> Vclazz) {
        try {
            Constructor<V> constructor = Vclazz.getConstructor(model.getClass());
            return constructor.newInstance();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This should work for all Views and Models. Note that you need to pass the `Class` of concrete view, since is not possible to obtain it at runtime.